# Looping through labels in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, label

I have nine labels with the names `"lbl101"`, `"lbl102"`, ...

I want to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    sting name = "lbl10" + i;
    name.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: String does not have a BackColor property.

Comment: Please confirm whether this is Windows Forms, WPF, or HTML forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the controls to a collection, and loop through that.

```
var labels = new List<Label> { lbl101, lbl102, lbl103 };

foreach (var label in labels)  
{  
    label.BackColor = Color.Red;  
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want every `Label` on the `Form` that starts with "lbl10", you can use LINQ to query the collection of controls:

```
var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
                          .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("lbl10"))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: but what can I do in the case which I have 90 or 900 labels ?

Answer (score 4):

If labels are set on the form, you can use *Linq*:

```
  var labels = Controls // or MyPanel.Controls etc. if labels are on panel
    .OfType<Label>()
    .Where(label => label.Name.StartsWith("lbl10"));

  foreach (var label in labels)   
    label.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: It should be label.Name.StartsWith, you have a typo there.

Comment: @juunas: Thank you! `With` not `Width`, that's for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the container they are in and grab a reference to them.

```
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++)  
{  
   var label = (Label)yourForm.FindControl("lbl10" + i.ToString());  
   label.BackColor = Color.Red;  
}
```

Comment: You mean `yourForm.Controls["lbl10" + i]`

Comment: Where does the OP mention windows forms?

Comment: @StephenBrickner His label has a `.BackColor` property. That's a bit of a giveaway.

Comment: Maybe so, but that's not what's returned from `FindControl()`. But I guess we need the OP to confirm one way or another.

Comment: over the FindControl it says: 'myForm' does not contain a definition 'FindControl'

Comment: @Vexorei You need to replace that with your form name. I think the default web form name is Form1. Or whatever control name its in, panel, etc.

Comment: @StephenBrickner Yes I did it, but it still giving me the error

Comment: @Vexorei Is this for web forms (aspx) or is this for windows forms?

Comment: @StephenBrickner it's for windows form

Comment: Ok then I would go with Dmitry Bychenko's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing would be to list them all out:

```
lbl100.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl101.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl102.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl103.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl104.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl105.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl106.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl107.BackColor = Color.Red;
lbl108.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

This is the most straightforward way to do it.  If you really want to be fancy, you could put them all in an array and iterate over that:

```
Label[] labels = new Label[]{
    lbl100, lbl101, lbl102, lbl103, lbl104, lbl105, lbl106, lbl107, lbl108
};
for (int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
{
    labels[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Or, if you know that all the labels are children of a certain control and there are no other labels in that control, you could do this:

```
foreach (Control c in someControl.Controls)
{
    if (c is Label)
    {
        ((Label)c).BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void changebackground()
 {           
     Label mylabel;

     foreach (Control con in this.Controls) 
     {
         if (con.GetType() == typeof (Label)) //or any other logic
         {
             mylabel = (Label)con;
             mylabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Form, to point to a control, just call it with the following sentence

```
this.Controls[control name]
```

for example

```
this.Controls["label1"].BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

So the answer to your question

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{  
  this.Controls["lbl10" + i.ToString()].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```